# R* Tree overlap computation

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, r-tree

I was reading through [this implementation of the R* Tree](http://www.virtualroadside.com/blog/index.php/2008/10/04/r-tree-implementation-for-cpp/), and I noticed that they are calculating overlap differently from how the [paper](http://epub.ub.uni-muenchen.de/4256/1/31.pdf) defines it.

In the paper, overlap is defined as such:

> For a given node/rect **k**, compute the sum of area of the intersection between **k** and each sibling of **k** (not including **k**).

Overlap enlargement is then the delta of this value and what the overlap of the node **k** is if an item **r** is added to **k**.

Something like this:

```
childOverlapEnlargement(Node child, item r)
{
    childEnlarged = child.union(r);
    sum = 0;
    for(each sibling s of child which isn't node)
    {
        sum += area(childEnlarged.intersect(s)) - area(child.intersect(s));
    }
    return sum;
}
```

In the other implementation, they sort by the intersection area of a given node with the item being inserted. Something like this:

```
childOverlapEnlargement(Node node, item r)
{
    return area(node.intersect(r));
}
```

Obviously their implementation is computationally less intensive than the paper's definition. However, I can't find any obvious logic why the two computations should be equal.

So my questions are:

1. Do the two computations always end up with the same subtrees being picked? Why?
2. If they do result in different subtrees being picked, are the results better or close to as good as the paper's definition? Or was the choice made in error?

edit: re-read over their implementation and I realized they weren't comparing the intersection of two siblings, but the intersection of each potential leaf and the item being inserted. Strangely enough, they're picking the sibling which overlaps the least with the item being inserted. Wouldn't you want to insert into the node which overlaps the most with the item being inserted?

Comment: I can't answer your questions here, but can report that this implementation lives up to the expected O() performance expectations with tens of thousands of stored regions. (No relationship to the author, just choose that implemntation over a number of others to be found on the net when I really needed one; and found it to work well even if using visitors feels weird to me.)

Comment: That's good to know, I implemented a R* Tree using the paper's definition and this is the biggest bottleneck (~70-80% of computation time for an insertion).

Comment: I'd love to take a look at your implementation of the R* Tree. My experience with the implementation on virtualroadside gave good enough performance for our needs (less than 20-30 minutes inserting ~50 million 'objects' IIRC)

Comment: Looks like boost has a new spatial index library as of [version 1.54.0](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_54_0.html). More info: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/index.html

Comment: @BoLu I know the virtualroadside implementation is very efficient at inserting nodes, my question was about the quality of the spatial tree created, and their implementation produces a very different and often poorer-quality tree compared to a true R* tree implementation. Its implementation seems closer to a basic R tree, which doesn't have this extreme insertion penalty. I'll work on putting my code together and push it to a public repo when I have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the implementation you are looking at has bugs or is incorrect. Nobody is perfect.

Note that the R*-tree tries to minimize **overlap enlargement**, not overlap itself.

Some overlap will likely be unavoidable. If there already is overlap, you cannot expect this to decreate when inserting additional rectangles. But you can try to at least not increase the amount of overlap.

As for performance considerations, check whether you need to actually compute the intersection rectangles. Try to instead of computing `area(intersection())` to do a function `intersectionSize()`. This *does* make a difference. For example, if `A.maxX = 1` and `B.minX = 2` I can immediately give the intersection size of 0, without looking at any of the other dimensions.

Avoid eagerly precomputing all intersections etc. that you could need. Instead, compute only those that you actually need. **Profile** your code, and see if you can optimize the critical codepaths. There usually are some low hanging fruit there.

Comment: I implemented both "solutions" and for the datasets I tried the paper's definition creates better looking trees (closer to square regions, much less overlap). I have profiled my code and this code is indeed the bottle-neck (by quite a big margin, too). Re-read the paper and they agreed that the overlap enlargement computation is quite computationally expensive, even with only performing the calculation on a small subset of the nodes.

Comment: Have you tried hard enough to optimize this computation? Have for example a look at the way the ELKI people compute this? See this helper function: http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/browser/elki/trunk/src/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/data/spatial/SpatialUtil.java#L234
there also is a "relativeOverlap" function there. A lot of these optimizations may be Java specific though - avoiding object allocations.